# .net Directory Class have to close handle?

Tags: .net

when using the .NET Directory class methods like EnumerateFiles or GetFiles or GetDirectories I assume that they take hold of an unmanaged handle. How is that handle released? are they using IDispose?
I mean is there possibility of a handle leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `Directory` doesn't implement `IDisposable`, and in fact all its methods are static. The releasing of the unmanaged handle must be within each method - if you really want to see more, try looking into it with something like Reflector.

In fact, if you do this, you'll find an internal class called `FileSystemEnumerableIterator<T>`, which does implement `IDisposable` and whose `Dispose` method closes the handle.

Comment: this means that I as a user don't have to worry about it since they clean up by themselves?

Comment: As a developer, you have far more important things to worry about. As Oded says, there's never a cast iron guarantee, but these classes are used continually without issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean is there possibility of a handle leak?

There is always a *possibility*, but these classes have been used in many production systems and are thoroughly tested - they do not have leaks.

If you want to know how they are implemented - use a disassembler like ILSpy or Reflector to see how it is done.